# One element is given seperable and another purely inseperable then show that ...

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, separable-extension

Kindly help with the following question asked in my mid term exam which has been concluded.

> If u $\in F$ is separable over K and c $\in F$ is purely inseparable over K, then
> K(u,c) = K( u + c).

I am unable to get any idea on how this question will be solved. The irreducibility polynomial of u will be given by $x-u  \in K[x]$ and irreducibility polynomial of c will be given by $(x-c)^m \in F[x]$  for some m >1 , $m\in \mathbb{Z}$.

But I am unable to use it to prove K(u,c).  Let  I choose any polynomial in K(u+v) , so it will be given  by $ \frac{a_0 + a_1 (u+c) + a_2 (u+c)^2 +....}{ b_0 + b_1 (u+v) + b_2 (u+v)^2 ...}$ ,Now It is triavial to see that the polynomial also lies in K(u,v) .

If I choose a polynomial in K(u,v) then  I struggle to prove that it lies as K(u,v). I think here we have to use seperability but unable to use it.

So, Do u mind helping me? Also , I Hope my rest of argument is fine.

Answer (score 1):

We may assume $\operatorname{char}K=p>0$ (otherwise $c\in K$ and the statement is trivial). You already proved the inclusion $K(u+v)\subseteq K(u,c)$, for the other inclusion we only need to prove $u,c\in K(u+v)$. There is some $r\in\Bbb N$ with $c^{p^r}=d\in K$. Hence we have $(u+c)^{p^r}=u^{p^r}+d$, so $u^{p^r}\in K(u+c)$. Show

1. $K(u)$ is both separable and purely inseparable over $K(u^{p^r})$
2. $K(u)=K(u^{p^r})\subseteq K(u+c)$.
3. $u\in K(u+c)$
4. $c\in K(u+c)$

Conclude $K(u,c)\subseteq K(u+v)$ and then equality.

Comment: why there exists some r $\in \mathbb{N}$, with $ c^{p^r}=d\in K$ ? in line 3 of your answer.

Comment: @No-One This follows from the assumption that $c$ is purely inseparable over $K$. Because for those elements the minimal polynomial is of the form $x^{p^r}-d$ for $d\in K$

Comment: Why if Char K=0 then $c\in K$? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: I am sorry but I am unable to prove any of 1-4  which you mentioned I should prove. Can you please fill up some hints on how to approach 1-4? I shall be really thankful

Comment: For the first question: what purely inseparable extensions can a field of characteristic $0$ have? For the second question: 1. It is sufficient to show that $u$ is both separable and purely inseparable over $K(u^{p^r})$. For the first one look at the assumptions given in the problem. For the second recall/look up in course notes/the book you are using what it means for an element $u$ to be purely inseparable over a subfield in terms of powers of the form $u^{p^r}$ (or look at my comment above). 2.: Deduce $K(u)=K(u^{p^r})$ using 1. The inclusion $K(u^{p^r})\subseteq K(u+c)$ follows from the

Comment: first paragraph ($u^{p^r}\in K(u+c))$. 3 follows from 2. Also, 4 follows from 3 (since $u,u+c\in K(u+c))
$

Comment: Can you please tell why proving 1 and 2 is necessary to prove $K(u,c)\subseteq K(u+c)$?